# How to run code coverage for Java project in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

How to run test coverage build in Idea 2022.2.3 (currently the latest) for a Gradle managed Java project?

[image: Run with Coverage toolbar button]

The toolbar button "Run with Coverage" action is disabled and run configurations for both "Gradle" and "JUnit" task types doesn't seem to contain any of *Code coverage* configuration tab and *Modify options* > *Add Run Options* > *Coverage settings* sub-menu referred in the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-test-with-coverage.html). The documentation also mentions

> Run configurations are currently being redesigned

Actual run configurations

[image: Gradle test run configuration]

[image: JUnit run configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be present, but it looks like you Coverage plugin is disabled, check it in Preferences | Plugins | Code Coverage for Java